# how to calculate the length of a string without spaces in java

Tags: java, string, integer

this calculate the whole length of the string eg i am a man= 7 letter and 9 characters i just want the amount of the total letters

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AssignmentProgramming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string");

        String input = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(input);

        String str = input;
        String[] myString = str.split(" ");
        int length = str.length();
        System.out.println(length);
    }

}
```

Comment: You couldn't just google `java remove space from string`?? Or better yet, your exact question `java string length without spaces` *also* turns up results that would answer your question.

Comment: This site is not intended for posting your class assignments and waiting for other people to solve them for you, sorry.

Answer (score 11):

You could try replacing all empty spaces by zero char:

```
String test = "Hello world    1 2 3 4 5";
System.out.println(test.replace(" ", "").length());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int characters = 0;
for (int i = 0, length = string.length(); i < length; i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
    characters++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for a one-liner. Why not just `str.replace(" ","").length()`? Also, your `string.length` needs a pair of parentheses.

Comment: a) There's no need to downvote a working solution just because it's not the same as your own. (Not sure if you were the downvoter or someone else.) b) string.replace can perform poorer, which is why I suggested a simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class cont

    {
        public static void main(String arg[]){
        int sum=0;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter string");
        String val=s.nextLine();
        int len=val.length();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                if(val.charAt(i)==' ')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    sum++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps you out !!

```
import java.util.*;
public class CountCharacters 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println("Entered a string ");
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
String originalString=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Entered string is "+originalString);
String newString=originalString.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println("New string after removing spaces is "+newString);
System.out.println("Number of characters in string are "+newString.length());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could also be a solution (replace-function) ...

```
String input = sc.nextLine();    

System.out.println(input);

String inputWithoutSpace = input.replace(" ", "")  

int length = inputWithoutSpace.length();    
System.out.println(length);
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer. However this seems to be basically the same as the top rated answer so it'd be better to upvote that answer instead.